# 301 redirect apache shows wrong url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

it turns out that for different reasons have had to change my website URL, the url old are indexed in Google and I want you to go through them, the new content is displayed with the new url.

I added this:

```
Redirect 301 /library/books/pitz-lower.php http://www.example.com/library/pitz-lower.php
```

But to get from google, the url in the browser looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/library/pitz-lower.php?url=library/pitz-lower
```

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]




RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /library/library\.php\?url=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /library/%1.php? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library/library\.php
RewriteRule ^library/(.+)\.php$ /library/library.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

#r301

Redirect 301 /library/books/pitz-lower.php http://www.example.com/library/pitz-lower.php
```

I do not understand why this happens, someone gives me a hand? Thank you !!

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean by "But to get from google"?

Comment: I edit the post, thanks ! Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. Mixing `mod_rewrite` rules and `mod_alias` rules (i.e. `Redirect` directive) is not good as these 2 modules run at different times.
2. Keep `301` redirect rules before internal rewrite ones.

Your modified .htaccess should be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^library/books/pitz-lower\.php$ /library/pitz-lower.php [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /library/library\.php\?url=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /library/%1.php? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library/library\.php
RewriteRule ^library/(.+)\.php$ /library/library.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache while testing this.

Comment: You're big, very big, it has been solved completely, impressive. Many thanks !!